# RegEx fails on checking maximum length

Tags: regex, preg-match

```
$regex = '/^(.+){,16}$/'
```

Nothing is matching, everything fails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. `{,16}` matches the characters `{,16}` literally, you should use `{0,16}`
2. You have 2 quantifiers so instead of `.+{,16}` you should use `.{0,16}`

Regex that should work for you:

```
$regex = '/^.{0,16}$/'; // will match empty input also
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY9qA9/1)

Comment: thank you..it worked..bt cant understand what are lazy and greedy quantifiers

Comment: There is lazy quantifier in `^.{0,16}$`. [Read this very good article on quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)